# How to work out answer to big modulus

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let us say that there is a number $899$ which is the product of $29$ and $31$.

I want to work out the following:
$$245^3 \pmod{899}$$

I know there is a way of doing it with $\phi(29)$ and $\phi(31)$ but I am not too sure. How do I break it down and do it more efficiently by hand?

Thank you

Comment: You can certainly work it out $\pmod {29}$ and $\pmod {31}$ and then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to get the solution $\pmod {899}$.  I'm not sure that's any easier or quicker than just working it out directly though.

Comment: @lulu how would I do this Sir/Madam

Comment: Fermat's little theorem (with the $\phi$) isn't going to help you much because the exponent is so small already. I think I would just calculate $245^3$ modulo $29$ and $31$ directly.

Comment: Well, let's do $29$.  We have $245\equiv  13\pmod {29}$ and then we get $13^2=169\equiv 24$ so $13^3\equiv 13\times 24\equiv 22\pmod {29}$.  The case of $31$ is similar.

Comment: But, honestly, just do it directly.  The numbers are all so small!  $245^2=60025\equiv 691\pmod {899}$.  So $245^3\equiv 245\times 691\equiv 283\pmod {899}$.  The Chinese Remainder Theorem is a great idea when the numbers get so large that you really want to avoid the big multiplies.  Here you never get worse than the product of two $3$ digit numbers.

Comment: @lulu how would you use the chinese remainder theorem? I eventually want to try bigger numbers

Comment: I'll post a brief calculation below.

Comment: @lulu You can also use $245\equiv -16 \bmod 29$ because $16^3=2^{12}$ might be easier, or also $245\equiv 100 \bmod 29$ because $5\times 29=145$ - such computational tricks are probably redundant here, but can help to simplify in more complex cases. (also $24\equiv -5$ simplifies arithmetic)

Comment: @MarkBennet  Good points throughout.

Answer (score 2):

First we solve the problem $\pmod  {29}$ and $\pmod {31}$.  We get $$245\equiv 13\pmod {29}\implies 245^2\equiv 169\equiv 24\pmod {29}\implies 245^3\equiv 13\times 24\equiv 22\pmod {29}$$

Thus we know that $$245^3=22+29n$$ for some integer $n$.

A similar computation $\pmod {31}$ shows $$245^3\equiv 4 \pmod {31}$$

We want to compute $245^3 \pmod {29\times 31}$.  By the Chinese Remainder Theorem there is a unique residue class $a$ such that $$a\equiv 22\pmod {29}\quad \&\quad a\equiv 4\pmod {31}$$

Thus, given that $245^3=22+29n$  we need to solve for $n\pmod {31}$ such that $$22+29n\equiv 4 \pmod {31}\implies 18\equiv -29n\equiv 2n\pmod {31}\implies n\equiv 9 \pmod {31}$$

Finally, we see that $$245^3\equiv 22+29\times 9\equiv 283\pmod {899}$$ and we are done.

As a check, I suggest doing the problem directly.  First check that $245^2\equiv 691\pmod {899}$ and then that $$245^3\equiv 691\times 245\equiv 283\pmod {899}$$.

Comment: Right where did the 18 come from?

Comment: Oh, if $22+29n=4$ then $18=22-4=-29n$.

Comment: The point here is that the Chinese Remainder Theorem works "layer by layer". First we solve the problem $\pmod {29}$ and $\pmod {31}$.  Then to solve it $\pmod {29\times 31}$ we just have to solve a linear congruence.  As I said, in the comments, for very small numbers, as here, this is not easier than the brute force method.  But if, say, you are working with $50$ digit primes instead of $2$ digit primes, it becomes critical to avoid the giant multiplications.